# Function returns undefined after first click

Tags: javascript, html

I have unordered list with 4 list items.

When i click on one list item class 'active' from other items should be deleted and clicked item should get it.

```js
function activeBool() {
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function change() {
  let current = activeBool();
  buttons[current].classList.remove("active");
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.add("active");
    });
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", change);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Wordpress</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Web Apps</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ecommerce</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a></li>
</ul>
```

Problem is that code simlpy does not get executed first time, after second click it works fine.
After first click `buttons[current]` is somehow undefined.

Comment: it won't work because you first button click executes `change`

Comment: Where does `buttons` come from?

Comment: @MosiaThabo `buttons` is defined, `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".holder li a");`

Comment: I know you probably defined `buttons` somewhere. My comment meant to make you realize that `change()` method is called on the first click, that's why nothing is happening and changes only occur on second click. You can check my suggestion below on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attached eventlistener doesn't make sense. It's working the second time because then you have added a new eventlistener in the change function.

I've modified your code, see my example below.

```js
var buttons = Array.from(document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li'));

function setActive(ev) {
  buttons.forEach(btn => btn.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].classList.remove('active'));
  ev.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].classList.add('active');
}

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', setActive));
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Wordpress</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Web Apps</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ecommerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work the first time because your first click calls `change`.

Try this out:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("ul li a");

function toggleClass(e) {
    removeActiveClassName(buttons);
    e.target.classList.add("active");
}

function removeActiveClassName(buttonList){
    buttonList.forEach((button) =>  button.classList.remove("active"));
}

window.addEventListener('load', ()=>
{
    buttons.forEach(function forEachButton(button, i){
        button.addEventListener("click", toggleClass);
        button.setAttribute("data-index", i); // In case you need the index later on
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}

a{
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Wordpress</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Web Apps</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ecommerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a></li>
</ul>
```